# Ideas behind the Grünfeld defense

Tags: opening, grunfeld-defense

I started a game (with the black pieces) where I have the possibilty to play the Grünfeld that I never played before.

> 1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 **d5**

I want to know what's the main idea behind it, especially for black, since I heard that it could lead to sharp positions and complications (even Kasparov had a hard time playing it against Karpov)

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but check out Dereque Kelley's Grunfeld video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2A-pYN5nCK4

Comment: For starters, you could look at [this question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5173/what-are-the-main-strategic-concepts-in-the-grunfeld).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main idea behind the Grünfeld is that Black momentarily concedes the center to White, only to attack it later.

For example, in the [Exchange variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%BCnfeld_Defence#Exchange_Variation:_4.cxd5_Nxd5_5.e4), White often gets a pawn center (c3, d4, e4) while Black will put it under pressure (especially aimed at the white d-pawn). Below is a diagram with a typical pawn structure for this variation, and some black pieces on squares where they can often be found.

```
[FEN "3r2k1/pp2ppbp/2n3p1/q1p5/3PP3/2P5/P4PPP/4K3 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer fits more what I was asking for than the former post answer !